# How to use System::Net::Mail in console application

Tags: c++

How i can use this >> System::Net::Mail; namespace in c++ console application?

Maybe im asking fool question but im new in cpp
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx#Y1320)

```
static void CreateTestMessage2( String^ server )
{
  String^ to = L"jane@contoso.com";
  String^ from = L"ben@contoso.com";
  MailMessage^ message = gcnew MailMessage( from,to );
  message->Subject = L"Using the new SMTP client.";
  message->Body = L"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
  SmtpClient^ client = gcnew SmtpClient( server );

  // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
  // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
  client->UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  client->Send( message );
  client->~SmtpClient();
}
```